# How to define if else statement whereby the else statement can remove unwanted \t

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a function, where one part reads as follows:

```
conefor.input <- function(conefor.file, onlyoverall, probmin, index)
{
for(i in 1:l00)
{
cat(paste(conefor.file,
        if(onlyoverall=="TRUE")
                {onlyoverall<-"onlyoverall"},
distance,
        if(probmin=="TRUE")
            {probmin<-paste("-pcHeur", min)}, 
 index, sep="\t"),file="conef_command.txt", sep="\n")}
return("conef_command.txt")
}
```

My objective is to generate 100 lines where each input is divided by a tab.

There is no problem when the two 'if' statements above are true. With the resulting being:

```
conefor.file\tonlyoverall\tdistance\tpcHeur min\tindex
```

However, when the two 'if' statements above are false, I am left with two tabs where 'onlyoverall' and 'pcHeur' would have been, whereas, what I really want is no action at all, and only one tab separating each argument.

Example when 'if' statements are false:

```
conefor.file\t\tdistance\t\tindex
```

What I want when 'if' statements are false:

```
conefor.file\tdistance\tindex
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: forgive me for missing what may be obvious, but I cannot spot any difference between iterations.  How is one iteration different from another?  (ie, there is no reference to `i` or anything similar that I can notice).

Comment: Question that involve tortured logic should be accompanied by test data.

Comment: @Dwin, there is nothing in this question, so far as the logic portion is concerned, that is data-dependent, just a bunch of variable names.  The function itself of course, is a different story

Comment: The assignments (in the code above and in your revision below) are superfluous and there is no apparent purpose to the for-loop, since there is no reference to the loop index in the body of the loop. So I thought a test case where there was a call to this function with a data argument would offer a better chance of producing useful code. At the moment it appears a `rep()` call could be substituted for the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to suggest any form of vectorization or similar for your `for` loop, since it's not clear (to me at least)
what differences there are between iterations.

However, as for the `paste` statement inside of `cat`, you can use the following instead

```
paste(ifelse(onlyoverall, 
          paste(conefor.file, onlyoverall<-"onlyoverall", sep="\t"),
          conefor.file),
      ifelse(probmin, 
            paste(distance, probmin<-paste("-pcHeur", min), sep="\t"), 
            distance),
      index, 
      sep="\t")
```

Notice, this grabs the output prior to the `if` statement and includes in an `ifelse` output, where it is given for both `TRUE` and `FALSE`

eg:

```
x1 <- x2 <- TRUE
paste(ifelse(x1, paste("A", "B" , sep="#"), "A"), ifelse(x2, paste("C", "D", sep="#"), "C"), "E", sep="#")
# [1] "A#B#C#D#E"

x1 <- x2 <- FALSE
paste(ifelse(x1, paste("A", "B" , sep="#"), "A"), ifelse(x2, paste("C", "D", sep="#"), "C"), "E", sep="#")
#  [1] "A#C#E"

x2 <- TRUE
paste(ifelse(x1, paste("A", "B" , sep="#"), "A"), ifelse(x2, paste("C", "D", sep="#"), "C"), "E", sep="#")
#  [1] "A#C#D#E"
```

Comment: @DanielleRappaport, no problem and glad to help.   That `for` loop though still seems questionable.  Are you sure it is doing what you expect from it?